# using where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm using postgre sql and I have a problem with where clause.

What I wanted to do was:

1. compare each month's data to that of previous month
2. select location where august to july ratio was lower than 0.7

Below is my code. I used *cast as decimal* because without that the result was just integers (either 0 or 1).

If I run the query, it does not return any results. It doesn't say error, but that there is no data where august < 0.7 (But there is! I checked in the original table without the where clause)

```
SELECT  location
      , round(cast(june as decimal)/may, 3) as june
      , round(cast(july as decimal)/june, 3) as july
      , round(cast(august as decimal)/july, 3) as august
FROM per_country
WHERE august < 0.7
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reuse an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause. You need to repeat the expression, or use a derived table (subquery, cte):

```
SELECT  location
      , round(june::numeric/may, 3) as june
      , round(july::numeric/june, 3) as july
      , round(august::numeric/july, 3) as august
FROM per_country
WHERE august::numeric/july < 0.7
```

Note that your existing query indicates of a bad design. You should not be storing each month in a separate table, for many reasons (scalability, efficiency, maintainability, ...). Instead, you should have each month on a separate row.